# How to make a terminal window open at a certain location by default

Tags: linux, linux-mint, terminal, path

Running Linux Mint 17.1 & MATE 1.8.1

When I open the terminal window with ctrl+T, I want it to switch the path automatically to ~/workspace. How do I do this?